# CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE + CUDA 7.5

Tags: c++, random, cuda, nvidia

My code is as follows:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define gpuErrorCheckCurand(ans) { gpuAssertCurand((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
#define gpuErrorCheckCuda(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

const char* curandGetErrorString(curandStatus_t status)
{
    switch(status)
    {
    case CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS: return "CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS";
    case CURAND_STATUS_VERSION_MISMATCH: return "CURAND_STATUS_VERSION_MISMATCH";
    case CURAND_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED: return "CURAND_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";
    case CURAND_STATUS_ALLOCATION_FAILED: return "CURAND_STATUS_ALLOCATION_FAILED";
    case CURAND_STATUS_TYPE_ERROR: return "CURAND_STATUS_TYPE_ERROR";
    case CURAND_STATUS_OUT_OF_RANGE: return "CURAND_STATUS_OUT_OF_RANGE";
    case CURAND_STATUS_LENGTH_NOT_MULTIPLE: return "CURAND_STATUS_LENGTH_NOT_MULTIPLE";
    case CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED: return "CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED";
    case CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE: return "CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE";
    case CURAND_STATUS_PREEXISTING_FAILURE: return "CURAND_STATUS_PREEXISTING_FAILURE";
    case CURAND_STATUS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED: return "CURAND_STATUS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED";
    case CURAND_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH: return "CURAND_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";
    case CURAND_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR: return "CURAND_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";
    }
    return "Unknown cuRAND error";
}

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=false) {
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("GPU assert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

inline void gpuAssertCurand(curandStatus_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=false) {
    if (code != CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS) {        
        printf("GPU (CURAND) assert: %s %s %d\n", curandGetErrorString(code), file, line);
    if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}


int main() {
    curandGenerator_t generator;
    int n = 100;
    gpuErrorCheckCurand(curandCreateGenerator(&generator, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT));
    gpuErrorCheckCurand(curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(generator, 1234ULL));
    float* uniformDevice; gpuErrorCheckCuda(cudaMalloc(&uniformDevice, n * sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrorCheckCurand(curandGenerateUniform(generator, uniformDevice, n)); 
    gpuErrorCheckCurand(curandDestroyGenerator(generator));
    gpuErrorCheckCuda(cudaFree(uniformDevice));
}
```

I compile the code above with a command:

```
nvcc rand.cu -lcurand
```

For a record my graphic card is GTX 1060 and I'm using CUDA 7.5 with driver version 375.39. The issue is an error status **CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE** during generation random numbers. The result from cuda-memcheck is:

```
Program hit cudaErrorInvalidDeviceFunction (error 8) due to "invalid device function" on CUDA API call to cudaGetLastError.
```

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to switch to CUDA 8.

The CURAND library in CUDA 7.5 was inadvertently built without PTX for forward compatibility, so it cannot be used on Pascal (cc 6.x) GPUs.

There is some additional discussion of this [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/941354/all-curand-samples-fail-with-gtx-1080-on-cuda-7-5/).

FWIW your code runs without any runtime error for me on a cc 6.1 GPU on CUDA 8.